# Can I use CHAR datatype for multiple codepages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

As the topic says.

I'm expecting data deliveries from various SQL Databases and (Excel) flat files with most likely different locales into my MS SQL Database.

Can I use CHAR and VARCHAR datatypes in my staging DB or do I need to switch to NCHAR / NVARCHAR?

My gut tells me I need NCHAR/NVARCHAR but I couldn't find a definite answer.

For brevity's sake let's assume all incoming data only contains latin letters and numbers (no korean text or similar)

Comment: NCHAR/NVARCHAR. Definite answer.

Comment: If all of your incoming data fits into your default code page, then you can do that. However, if you have information coming in from places with definitely different code pages, such as Chinese or Korean, you will need to use NVarchar. Your current character set is likely to be CP 1252 compatible, which can handle many, but not all, special characters used in Europe (Greek, for example, is right out.)  For safety sake, use NChar/NVarchar.